# heat map with one log axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a dataframe in which a single dependent variable (y) has a ~log-linear relationship with independent variable, x1, and a ~sigmoidal relationship with independent variable, x2.

```
df<-data.frame(x1 = rep(c(0:10),11),
           x2 = rep(c(0:10), each=11),
           logx1 = log(rep(c(0:10),11)+1),
           y = 0)

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) df[i,4] = exp(df[i,2]) * (1/(1+exp(-df[i,1])))
```

I want to display changes in y with respect to variation in x1 and x2 using a heat map:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x1, y=x2, fill=y))+
 theme_bw()+
 scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")+
 geom_tile(size=0.01)
```

but it's difficult to see the variation in y with respect to x1, so I want to plot x1 on a log scale:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=logx1, y=x2, fill=y))+
 theme_bw()+
 scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")+
 geom_tile(size=0.01)+
```

but it results in large spaces between the data, as opposed to a continuous surface of color:
[gaps in heat map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vpUJ.png)

I've tried:

converting x1 to a factor and plotting:

```
df$x1<-factor(df$x1, levels = sort(unique(df$x1)))
```

plotting as a raster with interpolate:

```
geom_raster(interpolate = TRUE
```

transforming the axis itself:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,1,10)+1, limits = c(0,10)+1, trans = 'log')
```

changing plot size with coord_equal() and coord_fixed(),

increasing the resolution of the data (i.e. estimate y for every 0.001 change in x1)

but I can't get the spaces to go away!

I'm not necessarily sold on a heat map, but I need to display variation in y with respect to both x1 and x2 and I need to do it in ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `y ~ exp(x)` as in your example, then placing y (not x) on a log scale might be a better way to display their relationship. E.g.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x1, y=x2, fill=log(y))) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_tile(size=0.01)
```

[image: heatmap 1]
Alternately you could display x on an exponential scale (note that in your example it's actually x2 that has a log-linear relationship with y, and x1 sigmoidal). If you want to display a continuous-surface heat map with x2 on an exponential scale, you need points for x2 that are equally spaced on an exponential scale. One way to get equally-spaced points is the `pretty()` function. E.g.

```
# generate new data with x2 equally space on exp scale
newdat <- expand.grid(x1 = pretty(df$x1, 10), exp_x2 = pretty(exp(df$x2), 10))

# backtransform exp_x2
newdat$x2 <- log(newdat$exp_x2) 

# generate y values (using raw x2 values, not exp_x2)
newdat$y <- exp(newdat$x2) * (1/(1+exp(-newdat$x1)))

# plot    
ggplot(newdat, aes(x=x1, y=exp_x2, fill=y)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_tile(size=0.01)
```

[image: heatmap 2]

Comment: Plotting y on a log axis would be inappropriate for the actual data I have, but certainly is a good solution for this example (an MWE).

I did end up using something similar to your second posting and it works well, thanks!